# MySql retrieve rows based on difference between first and last relation

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, relational-database

I have two tables `item` and `price`. The `item` table has a number of `price` records added to it over time. these `price` records have a `price` field storing the `item` price at that given time, e.g:

```
Price table
id_item          timestamp               price
1                2014-27-10 00:00:00     10
1                2014-27-10 01:00:00     20
2                2014-27-10 00:00:00     10
2                2014-27-10 01:00:00     30
etc...
```

What I need to do is select the top 5 `item`'s based on the `price` increase and I'm not sure if this is possible by joining the `price` table twice, for example using `startPrice` and `endPrice` as aliases and then adding to the `where` clause the difference between the two prices, for example something like this (does not work):

```
SELECT `i`.*,
   `pStart`.`price` `startPrice`,
   `pEnd`.`price` `endPrice`,
   SUM(`startPrice` - `endPrice`) as `diffPrice`
FROM `item` `i`
INNER JOIN `price` `pStart`
   ON `pStart`.`id_item` = `i`.`id`
INNER JOIN `price` `pEnd`
   ON `pEnd`.`id_item` = `i`.`id`
  AND `pEnd`.`timestamp` = (
       SELECT MAX(`timestamp`)
       FROM `price`
       WHERE `id_item` = `i`.`id`)
GROUP BY `i`.`name`
```

Without the `SUM(startPrice - endPrice) as diffPrice` line it returns the startPrice and endPrice correctly, but I can't work out how to order by the price "increase" between the two prices and then limit to 5 results in all?

I'm not sure if I should be going down this route or a series of subqueries in the main select? Although I can cache the query result to lighten the load, I know subqueries can be very slow.

[Edit]

Thanks for the comment Strawberry, I've added an sql fiddle here as suggested:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8caf/3

The output I'd be looking to achieve in this example is:

```
Item.name     Price difference

Item7         70
Item6         60
Item5         50
Item4         40
Item3         30
```

Comment: If it's any consolation, I think you're quite close. But I thjnk it'd be easier to help if you followed this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry, have added that to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query, you don't really need aggregation at the outer level.  Instead, find the minimum and maximum timestamp and then joining in the price information based on that:

```
SELECT i.start, ps.price as startPrice, pe.price as endPrice,
       (pe.price - ps.price) as diffPrice
FROM item i INNER JOIN
     (SELECT p.id_item, MIN(p.timestamp) as mints, MAX(p.timestamp) as maxts
      FROM price
      GROUP BY p.id_item
     ) pp JOIN
     price ps
     ON ps.id_item = i.id AND ps.timestamp = pp.mints JOIN
     price pe
     ON pe.id_item = i.id AND pe.timestamp = pp.maxts
ORDER BY diffPrice DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - however it's the `(endPrice - startPrice) as diffPrice` line causing the issues again, I'm getting the error `#1054 - Unknown column 'endPrice' in 'field list'`

Comment: I've also added an SQLFiddle as Strawberry mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @Stu . . . Wishful thinking on my part.  You (nor I) can re-use aliases in the `select` clause.  I should have put in the column references.

Comment: Bingo, I think that's bang on, thank you. And to obtain price changes from today only (next challenge!), I think I just need to add a `WHERE` clause for timestamp between two midnights on the end of the join `SELECT p.id_item, MIN(p.timestamp) as mints, MAX(p.timestamp) as maxts` line.

Comment: @Stu . . . It sounds like that should work.  If it doesn't, you should ask another question.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . I removed it.  It seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This solution rather relies on the fact that there are only two values for each item...

```
 SELECT i.name
      , x.price-y.price diff 
   FROM item i 
   JOIN price x 
     ON x.id_item = i.id 
   JOIN price y 
     ON y.id_item = x.id_item 
    AND y.id < x.id 
  ORDER
     BY diff DESC
  LIMIT 5
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8caf/15

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! :) Unfortunately there will be a shed load of values for each item, I just uploaded two to the fiddle to speed things up!

Comment: @Stu Then that was an oversimplification. For instance, we can't tell if you're looking for the biggest difference in price overall or the biggest difference in price between the latest value and the preceding value. Anyway, Gordon seems to have cracked it.

Comment: very true, apologies! Next time I'll make sure to be clear... adding a few extra rows would have made that a bit more obvious, yeah!